# How does Arrays.asList(T... a) return an interface?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I am looking at the Java API from Oracle, particularly at this method that is part of the `java.util.Arrays` class:

`public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)`

But how is it possible that this method is returning a List object when clearly it is an interface?

Comment: A method can return a interface. The returned object is an instance of class that implements the interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It is called **polymorphism**
- It means you can refer to a subtype using supertype reference
- In this case, the method is returning instances of class that implement the `List` interface

Source code of [Arrays.asList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.asList%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method

```
 public static <T> List<T> More ...asList(T... a) {
   return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}
```

Comment: Just as a note: The `ArrayList` of that method isn't `java.util.ArrayList`, instead it is a private inner class of the `Arrays` class: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.ArrayList

Answer (score 4):

Any method that has an interface type as its return type actually returns an instance of some class that implements that interface. The point of having an interface type as the return type is allowing the developer of the method to change the implementation that the method returns without changing the API.

In the case of `Arrays.asList`, an instance of `Arrays$ArrayList` (a nested class inside the `Arrays` class) is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Method will return the child class object. Check the source code of java

```
public static <T> List<T> More ...asList(T... a) {
        return new ArrayList<T>(a);
  }
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.asList%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29

Read the polymorphism as well

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm

Comment: just a suggestion. Can you change `child class object` to `subtype`? I feel child class object is implying that supertype i.e. List is a class and not interface. Saying supertype or subtype will be application for both interfaces and classes.

Answer (score 2):

It is returning *a reference to any instance of List*. Now, any class that *implements the List interface* is also a List. example `ArrayList` is a `List`.

That being said, the method returns an instance of a List. 
**Note that the list instance returned cannot be cast explicitly to `java.util.ArrayList`, the actual instance returned is of type `Arrays$ArrayList`**